# yii2 gridview calculate model attribute with it's reference attribute

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have 2 tables called 'PO' and 'Agen'.
Table PO have reference to Agen (agen_id attribute).
When viewing in the gridview from index.php PO, 
i want to calculate $model->netto ($PO->netto) with $Agen->fee.

```
[
        'class'=> 'kartik\grid\FormulaColumn', 
        'header' => 'Subtotal Fee Agen',
        'value' => function($model){
            //return var_dump($model);
            return ($model->netto * fee);
        },
        'format'=>['decimal', 0],
        'hAlign' => 'right'
    ],
```

I have still no luck with this. Unknown property error.
Please advice. thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$model` being the instance of `PO` and `$agen` being the instance of `Agen` passed from the controller use inside the grid:

```
'value' => function ($model) use ($agen) {
    return $model->netto * $agen->fee;
},
```

If I got it correctly and you have relation set `getAgen()` in `PO` using `agen_id` so you can reach `Agen` like:

```
$fee = $model->agen->fee;
```

you can use it like that:

```
'value' => function ($model) {
    return $model->netto * $model->agen->fee;
},
```

Comment: awesome. this is work. thanks alot. 'value' => function ($model) {
    return $model->netto * $model->agen->fee;
},